# Is there a way to convert a VBA module into a VBA string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to update the ThisWorkbook module in numerous excel files that get sent to me. I currently have a module that replaces all the .bas files with the .bas files in a specific folder. The best way I have found to replace the ThisWorkbook module is to add the text using this:

```
ThisWorkbookCode = "Sub ExampleCode1()" & vbCr & " Msgbox ""Hello""" & vbCr & "End Sub" & vbCr
SheetCode = "Sub ExampleCode2()" & vbCr & " Msgbox ""Hello again""" & vbCr & _
"'Extra text" & vbCr & "End Sub" & vbCr
WB.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString (ThisWorkbookCode)
```

My current ThisWorkbook text is 163 lines. Is there an easy way to transform

```
Sub ExampleCode1()
 MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Into

```
"Sub ExampleCode1()" & vbCr & " Msgbox ""Hello""" & vbCr & "End Sub" & vbCr
```

Or better yet is there an easier way to replace the current ThisWorkbook module with an updated one?

I tried using my .bas import/export but since ThisWorkbook already exists, it puts it in the Class Module folder, which is not what I want

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just keep the module code as a text file, then copy paste from that to the new module?

Comment: You probably want a Personal Binary Workbook that can store the module and then change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` and you can run it on any workbook you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner - ah didn't know you could copy from a text file. This looks like it should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of inserting code from a file:

```vb
Sub TestAdd()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'for example
    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines       'clear any existing content
        .AddFromFile "C:\Temp\testVBA.txt"  'add content from file
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Scott Craner for the idea. Posting the solution I ended up using. This will copy a text file and replace the text in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Sub Import_ThisWorkbook_Code()
    Dim MyData As String
    Dim strData() As String
    Dim ThisWorkbookCode As String

    Open "I:\New_ThisWorkbook.txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
    
    ThisWorkbookCode = MyData
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.CountOfLines
    
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents.item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString (ThisWorkbookCode)
    
    
    
End Sub
```